# Uni Test for Log in Page giving null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, testing, tdd

i am writing a unitest for login in my project .

when i call the login function of my controller. Memership.GetUser giving null value for passed User.
below is Test case

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Login()
    {

        //Arrange
        AccountController account = new AccountController(_forgotPasswordTokensRepo, _IMessageTemplateDAO, _IEmailService, _ISettingDAO, _IProfileDAO);
        List<AccountBO> TestUsers = new List<AccountBO>();

        AccountBO objAccountBO = new AccountBO();
        objAccountBO.Email = "uu@yopmail.com";
        objAccountBO.Password = "123456789";


        TestUsers.Add(objAccountBO);

        var result = (JsonResult)account.Login(TestUsers[0]);
        var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string data = result.Data.ToString().Split('=')[1].Trim();
        bool Processdata = Convert.ToBoolean(data.Replace('}', ' ').Trim());

        Assert.AreEqual<bool>(true, Processdata);



    }
```

Controller function is

```
public JsonResult Login(AccountBO account, string returnUrl = "")

    {

        bool hasBeenUnlocked = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           MembershipUser adminUser;
           adminUser = Membership.GetUser(account.Email);
           ------so on
       }

    }
```

here adminUser = Membership.GetUser(account.Email) is giving null.

Comment: Does you unit test for `Membership.GetUser(...)` succeed?

Comment: So fix that unit test first?

Comment: This isn't really about testing and definitely not about tdd. Depending on what you want it's either on stubbing the membership provider, or stubbing/mocking in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect `GetUser` to return? Are you expecting it to query the db/active directory and return a user with full credentials?

Unless I remember wrong, `Membership` is part of Asp.Net infrastructure so it is not set up in the context of your unit test. The solution is not to set it up. It is to stub out that functionality.

```
public interface IProvideUsers {
    public MembershipUser Get(string email, string password);
}

public class AspNetMembershipProvider : IProvideUsers {
    public MembershipUser Get(string email) {
         //...
    }
}
```

then in your controller

```
IProvideUsers users;
....
   users.Get(account.Email, account.Password);
```

where users is injected via the constructor. Then in your tests you create your own implmentation of `IProvideUsers` and provide that.